# Pandas ImportError: cannot import name 'OrderedDict' when I try to read a .csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

When I try to read a .csv file (which is created by pandas), pandas gives me this error:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv("./myfile.csv")


ImportError: cannot import name 'OrderedDict'
```

How can I fix this problem?

I use **python 3.6.7** and **pandas 0.25.0**

Comment: Try the full filename?

Comment: It's interesting as `OrderedDict` is a built-in implementation after Python2.7. Are you using the Python found in a cave?

Comment: @Sraw, I use python 3.6.7

Comment: @chucklukowski, full path you mean?

Comment: @woody yes, path

Comment: @chucklukowski, yeah, nothing happened. It still gives me the same error

Comment: Include a sample of your .csv file

Comment: Broken pandas ? can you try `pip install pandas` and see if it works?

Comment: This is peculiar, what would happen if you add `from collections import OrderedDict`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**It seems that something is not installed correctly.**

Try this before importing pandas and report the output you get:

```
try:
    from collections import OrderedDict
except ImportError:
    from ordereddict import OrderedDict

import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv("./myfile.csv")
```

Also **try to re-install pandas using:**

```
pip install pandas
```

https://pypi.org/project/pandas/

Comment: Thanks! The re-installation idea fixed the problem!